# Simple Game - adding a countdown after scoring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timer

I am creating a simple tennis game in Objective-C. Currently, when the player or the computer scores, it gives a message "tap to begin" and that releases the ball (it's a bit awkward to have your thumb on the racquet and another thumb to tap it to begin).

How do I add a timer into my game so that I don't have to tap after every score?

(This code is the resetting method when there is a new game and when there is a score)

```
{

self.gameState = kGameStatePaused;

ball.center = self.view.center;

if(newGame)

{
    if(computerScoreValue > playerScoreValue)

    {
        tapToBegin.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        tapToBegin.text = @"Computer Wins!";
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(booFileID);
    }

    else

    {
        tapToBegin.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        tapToBegin.text = @"You Win!";
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(clappingFileID);
    }

    computerScoreValue = 0;
    playerScoreValue = 0;
}
else
{
    tapToBegin.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    tapToBegin.text = @"Tap to Begin";

}
playerScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",playerScoreValue];
computerScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",computerScoreValue];

}
```

Comment: And what is the problem that you're having? What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: I haven't tried anything; I just do not know how to code it out.

Comment: You are probably going to want to use an NSTimer to accomplish this. It can get called when the "scoring" happens.

Comment: You should reformulate this as a specific question. As it's written, it's a little too vague. We don't know anything about how your game works, so suggesting something to you is nearly impossible. I don't understand what relevance the code posted has to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) should work. If you're curious take a look at [CADisplayLink](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) too.